# When processing a parsley form event is there a way to determine what group was validated

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I am using parsley.js for validation, and i have a set of fields assigned to a group. If that group of fields is validated and the form:success, form:error or form_validated events fire, is there a way in the event handler to determine the name of the group of fields that were validated and triggered the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't right now, but it would be a nice feature to have. PR accepted.